# Outputting after a delay on subscribe using rxjs operators

Tags: typescript, rxjs, operators, delay

I need to get an output like the following:

```
computing 1
5
6
7
8

wait 2 seconds

computing 2
5
6
7
8

wait 2 seconds
...
```

but with the following code

```
from([1,2,3,4]).pipe(
    concatMap(n => of(n).pipe(
        tap(n => {console.log(`computing ${n}`)}),
        concatMap(n => from([5,6,7,8])),
        delay(2000)
    ))
).subscribe((val) => {console.log(val)}, () => {}, () => {console.log(`end`)})
```

the output will be

```
computing 1

wait 2 seconds

5
6
7
8
computing 2

wait 2 seconds

5
6
7
8
computing 3
```

because the `delay` will take effect after the innermost flattening and cause next `computing x` string to be printed right after the value emissions. Instead, I need to get the above example output without getting an initial delay, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we set up a function that creates an observable that stays open for a length of time and then completes.

```js
const nothingFor = (ms) => timer(ms).pipe(concatMapTo(EMPTY));
```

Then we use it to make a new operator that behaves like `delay`*, but applies the delay after.

```js
const appendDelay = (delay) => (source$) =>
  of(source$, nothingFor(delay)).pipe(concatAll());
```

Then we just drop it in where you were originally using `delay`.

```js
from([1, 2, 3, 4])
  .pipe(
    concatMap((n) =>
      of(n).pipe(
        tap((n) => {
          console.log(`computing ${n}`);
        }),
        concatMap((n) => from([5, 6, 7, 8]).pipe(appendDelay(2000)))
      )
    )
  )
```

* well, sort of. `delay` delays each emission by the same amount. If this were more like `delay`, it would add a delay after each emission instead of after the source completes.

Answer (score 1):

The crux of this problem is, we want to introduce the delay only after the first emission of the first source observable.

We can use `concatMap` in conjunction with the `delayWhen` operator that lets us choose a conditional delay. The conditional delay can be built on top of the index of the iteration of the first observable. If the index is 0, there's no delay, otherwise, there's 2 seconds delay.

After the emission of every item in the first observable & post conditional delay, we switch to the second observable stream with `switchMap` which will help us get the required output.

```
import { from, iif, interval, of } from "rxjs";
import { concatMap, delayWhen, map, switchMap, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

const a$ = from([1, 2, 3, 4]);
const b$ = from([5, 6, 7, 8]);

const conditionalDelay$ = index => y =>
  iif(() => index === 0, interval(0), interval(2000));

const logDelay = index => () => {
  if (index !== 0) console.log("Wait for 2 seconds");
};

const result$ = a$.pipe(
  concatMap((x, index) =>
    of(x).pipe(
      tap(logDelay(index)),
      delayWhen(conditionalDelay$(index))
    )
  ),
  switchMap(x => {
    console.log("Computing", x);
    return b$.pipe(map(y => console.log(y)));
  })
);

result$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

One small adjustment to you code would get it working how you want.  Instead of simply returning your desired observable (`of`) inside your `concatMap`, you can return an observable that the first emits your desired observable, followed by an observable that emits nothing, then completes after a delay.

To accomplish this we can use [`concat`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/concat) and [`NEVER`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/const/NEVER):

```js
from([1,2,3,4]).pipe(
    concatMap(n => concat(
      of(n).pipe(
        tap(n => {console.log(`computing ${n}`)}),
        concatMap(n => from([5,6,7,8]))
      ),
      NEVER.pipe(takeUntil(timer(2000))) // emit nothing, then complete after 2000 ms
    ))
).subscribe((val) => {console.log(val)}, () => {}, () => {console.log(`end`)})
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-67244714?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) demo.